# Is it a good idea to license my app on the Android Licensing Service?

Tags: android, google-play, license-key

We are going to make the app available for .99 on the market, but is licensing it a must?  We are worried about the license query bugging the user/always requiring network access.  Should we definitely license regardless of our worries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a "must", but piracy is a big problem, and I would use the licensing library if I were you. FWIK it doesn't require the user to be always online, so it's not as intrusive as you might think it is.

People are weird - they don't think twice about buying a cup of coffee for $4 every day, but if they have the option of illegally downloading a pirated copy of a $0.99 app, they're very likely to do that instead of shelling out the buck and supporting the developer.

Comment: How long does the process take to license an app?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't give you details - I haven't done it myself. However, I think the process itself is pretty much automatic. The bigger challenge will be for you to obfuscate the code. Just plugging the licensing library in will get your app cracked in a very short time.